# How to simplify the output of a for loop function

Tags: r, for-loop, time-series, break

Here is a sample of my code, where each time step is dependant on the previous.

```
my_func <- function(n=100, con=0.95, t=35, m=0.047){
  G1<- numeric(length = t + 1)
  G2<- numeric(length = t + 1)
  G3<- numeric(length = t + 1)
  G4<- numeric(length = t + 1)
  G5<- numeric(length = t + 1)
  G6<- numeric(length = t + 1)
  G7<- numeric(length = t + 1)
  G8<- numeric(length = t + 1)
  G9<- numeric(length = t + 1)
  MC1<- numeric(length = t + 1)
  MC2<- numeric(length = t + 1)
  MC3<- numeric(length = t + 1)
  MC4<- numeric(length = t + 1)
  MC5<- numeric(length = t + 1)
  MC6<- numeric(length = t + 1)
  DC <- numeric(length = t + 1)
  NP <- numeric(length = t + 1)

  G1[1]<- rbinom(1,n,con)
  G2[1]<- 0
  G3[1]<- 0
  G4[1]<- 0
  G5[1]<- 0
  G6[1]<- 0
  G7[1]<- 0
  G8[1]<- 0
  G9[1]<- 0
  MC1[1]<- 0
  MC2[1]<- 0
  MC3[1]<- 0
  MC4[1]<- 0
  MC5[1]<- 0
  MC6[1]<- 0
  DC[1] <- 0
  NP[1] <- 100 - G1[1] 

  for(step in 1:t){
    G2[step+1] <- rbinom(1, G1[step], (1-m))
    G3[step+1] <- rbinom(1, G2[step], (1-m))
    G4[step+1] <- rbinom(1, G3[step], (1-m))
    G5[step+1] <- rbinom(1, G4[step], (1-m))
    G6[step+1] <- rbinom(1, G5[step], (1-m))
    G7[step+1] <- rbinom(1, G6[step], (1-m))
    G8[step+1] <- rbinom(1, G7[step], (1-m))
    G9[step+1] <- rbinom(1, G8[step], (1-m))
    MC1[step+1] <- rbinom(1, G9[step], (1-m))
    MC2[step+1] <- rbinom(1, MC1[step], (1-m))
    MC3[step+1] <- rbinom(1, MC2[step], (1-m))
    MC4[step+1] <- rbinom(1, MC3[step], (1-m))
    MC5[step+1] <- rbinom(1, MC4[step], (1-m))
    MC6[step+1] <- rbinom(1, MC5[step], (1-m))
    G1[step+1] <- rbinom(1, MC6[step],con)
    NP[step+1] <- MC6[step]-G1[step+1]
    DC[step+1] <- sum(G1[step]-G2[step+1],G2[step]-G3[step+1],G3[step]-
    G4[step+1],G4[step]-G5[step+1],G5[step]-G6[step+1],G6[step]-
    G7[step+1],G7[step]-G8[step+1],G9[step]-MC1[step+1],MC1[step]-MC2[step+1],MC2[step]-MC3[step+1],MC3[step]-MC4[step+1],MC4[step]-MC5[step+1],MC5[step]-MC6[step+1])

   }

  out <- cbind(G1, G2, G3, G4, G5, G6, G7, G8, G9, NP, MC1, MC2, MC3, MC4, 
MC5, MC6, DC)
  return(out)
 }
 my_func()
```

This returns the following output:

```
      G1 G2 G3 G4 G5 G6 G7 G8 G9 NP MC1 MC2 MC3 MC4 MC5 MC6 DC
 [1,] 99  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1   0   0   0   0   0   0  0
 [2,]  0 90  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0  9
 [3,]  0  0 87  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0  3
 [4,]  0  0  0 79  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0  8
 [5,]  0  0  0  0 77  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0  2
 [6,]  0  0  0  0  0 73  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0  4
 [7,]  0  0  0  0  0  0 68  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0  5
 [8,]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 63  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0  5
 [9,]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 61  0   0   0   0   0   0   0  0
[10,]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  53   0   0   0   0   0  8
[11,]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0  50   0   0   0   0  3
[12,]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0  47   0   0   0  3
[13,]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0  45   0   0  2
[14,]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0  44   0  1
[15,]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0  42  2
[16,] 41  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1   0   0   0   0   0   0  0
[17,]  0 40  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0  1
```

Is there a way to code this series so that the elements generated under columns `G1`-`G9` will be can be viewed in a single column `G` and the respective elements are seen in rows `[1,]`-`[9,]`? This concerns `MC1`-`MC6` and so forth for the other variables in the current code.

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE.

The desired output I am looking for is the following:

```
                 G          NP          MC          DC
 [1,]           99          1           0           0        
 [2,]           90          0           0           9        
 [3,]           87          0           0           3        
 [4,]           79          0           0           8        
 [5,]           77          0           0           2        
 [6,]           73          0           0           4        
 [7,]           68          0           0           5        
 [8,]           63          0           0           5        
 [9,]           61          0           0           2        
[10,]            0          0          53           8        
[11,]            0          0          50           3        
[12,]            0          0          47           3        
[13,]            0          0          45           2        
[14,]            0          0          44           1        
[15,]            0          0          42           2        
[16,]           41          1           0           0        
[17,]           40          0           0           1
```

Comment: You could probably work something out using `diag()` within the steps of your loop to extract the non-zero values of each iteration, store them in a vector and then bind them together.

Comment: Not clear, maybe try `x <- y <- z <- 1` to simplify some bits of your code? Also, read about *vectorization*

Comment: Can you post a sample output? Your question isn't very clear - looks like you want to reshape your data from wide to long, so you have columns G, MC, DC and NP at the end, correct?

Comment: Thank you all. I have uploaded a sample of the desired output @shreyasgm

Answer (score 1):

We use `rownames_to_column` so we can reconstruct the original order when we are finished.

We use `gather` to go from wide to long format. In this format, we can remove the numbers from what was the column names and sum up the values by the new column names (`key`).

Then we just have to put it back in its original format.

```
df %>%
  rownames_to_column %>%
  gather(key = 'key', value = 'value', -rowname) %>%
  mutate(key = stringr::str_extract(key,  '[a-zA-Z]+')) %>%
  group_by(rowname, key) %>%
  summarise(value = sum(value)) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  spread(key = 'key', value = 'value') %>%
  arrange(as.integer(rowname)) %>%
  select(G, NP, MC, DC)
# # A tibble: 17 x 4
#        G    NP    MC    DC
#    <int> <int> <int> <int>
#  1    99     1     0     0
#  2    90     0     0     9
#  3    87     0     0     3
#  4    79     0     0     8
#  5    77     0     0     2
#  6    73     0     0     4
#  7    68     0     0     5
#  8    63     0     0     5
#  9    61     0     0     0
# 10     0     0    53     8
# 11     0     0    50     3
# 12     0     0    47     3
# 13     0     0    45     2
# 14     0     0    44     1
# 15     0     0    42     2
# 16    41     1     0     0
# 17    40     0     0     1
```

Comment: Thank you, @Paul . Please excuse my naive question, but what does `%>%` mean? I only have three weeks experience with R.

Comment: @Francis_SU, the `%>%` operator is from the `maggritr` package (used as part of the `tidyverse` package) look up the `tidyverse` vignette to see how it's used.